# Xcode - Arc and storyboards - heap grow 6 - 10KB on each UIViewController switch

Tags: xcode, memory, storyboard, heap-memory, automatic-ref-counting

I'am using ARC and Storyboard on my new iPad project. I get no memory leaks, if I Analyze  with Instruments, but i'am getting a heap grow of 6KB - 10KB on each switch between the UIViewControllers. I'am using Storyboards build-in methods to do the switchs.

Why do I get a increase of 6-10KB ? - I know 6-10KB is not much, but I can't understand where they are coming from.

/Morten

Comment: I think that it is the @autoreleasepool that cause the heap grow - Should I care about that?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of memory usage could easily be attributed to usual allocations that would occur while presenting a new view controller. Alone, I can imagine that the memory needed for the new CALayers, UIViews, etc. would be enough to eat up this much memory. It may also be that, since you are using Story Board, certain pieces of XIB files are getting loaded into memory indefinitely.

These two factors are more than enough to explain why the memory is being allocated. Usually I wouldn't stop to worry about something like 10KB, considering that most iOS devices have around 250MB of memory at your disposal.